# Assigning variables during render event to phprenderer not passing to layout

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

i am trying to assign variables to my view renderer during an event i attached to the `render event` and its not producing values.

I have an event that i attached to the `render event` in my `Application Module`. I also have the method which gets called during the `render event operation` **This is a Zend Framework 3 Application however I tagged Zend Framework 2 for more exposure since the framework is very new.** Here it is

```
namespace Application;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $app->getEventManager()->attach('render', array($this, 'setAssignRouteVariables'));
    }

    public function setAssignRouteVariables(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $matches    = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $action     = $matches->getParam('action');
        $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');
        $designHandler = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('DesignHandler');   
        $designHandler->getPhprenderer()->controllerName='testcontroller';
        $designHandler->getPhprenderer()->actionName='testaction';
    }
}
```

If you look, I am calling the method `getPhprenderer()` using the `DesignHandler` class. This method returns an instance of `\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer`. **In any case after this i assign variables to the renderer object.**

Following this, `in my layout - application/view/layout/layout.phtml` i do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var currentController = '<?php echo $this->controllerName;?>';
   var currentAction = '<?php echo $this->actionName;?>';
</script>
```

**I'm getting `blank values` in this.**

What am I doing incorrectly here?

**Here's the current result**:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var currentController = '';
       var currentAction = '';
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
        public function setAssignRouteVariables(MvcEvent $e)
        {
            $matches    = $e->getRouteMatch();
            $action     = $matches->getParam('action');
            $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');     
            $e->getViewModel()->controllerName=$controller;
            $e->getViewModel()->actionName=$action;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $GLOBALS global variable instead. I faced same problem but did not find better solution.

```
$GLOBALS["my_index"] = "My value";
```

in javascript

```
var myval = '<?=$GLOBALS["my_index"]?>';
```